# pictures overlap text on a small resolution screen

Tags: html, css

I have a customer who wants the pictures flushed to each side problem is on different resolutions the pictures end up overlapping the text. is there another method that will keep the pics on the sides and re-size everything when the screen gets bigger?

his screen resolution is: 1152 x 864

this is the site : http://raandassociates.com/?page_id=55

Comment: well having them absolutely positioned to the edges will take them outside of the page flow and meant that they will overlap.

Comment: whats the best solution?

Comment: I would be using a column based liquid layout. Google for CSS column layouts and you should find a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Prefer liquid layout for your design. Put your middle content inside a single div and make it overflow : auto. Last adjust your image accordingly.